# devtools::release() Error in 'git2r_remote_fetch': unknown certificate check failure

Tags: r, devtools

I am trying to run devtools::release to submit a R package I have written to CRAN and I get the following error message:

```
devtools::release()
Checking if synched with remote branch...
ERROR: Error in 'git2r_remote_fetch': unknown certificate check failure
```

I have been able to upload and download my package from GitHub without issues in the past, and the version of the package on my computer is up to date with the version on GitHub.  The CMD checks on my computer throw up no issues.  Can anyone advise what might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a security issue (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/issues/559); I'm guessing you're using Windows). I had a similar problem, and was being suddenly asked for passwords all the time. I was able to resolve it by downloading and installing the latest version of Git from [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win). 
If you restart your R session, devtools should work properly with Github again.

Comment: Thanks - I am using windows. To submit the package I managed to use devtools::submit_cran() successfully, but I will update my version of Git and try again